# How can i Reset my activity with the press of a button

Tags: android

I want to reset my activity, there are few functions and methods being performed in my class and i want that when i press the button everything resets and comes to a start just like at first how the activity gets started.

Comment: while all the answers are telling you to completely restart the activity. I would say thats is a sketchy work around. The correct implementation would be have a method that resets everything manually if possible.

Comment: I also had the same desire, I've built a debug mechanism that changes the application locale and refresh any screen http://android-know-how-to.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/multi-language-android-application.html , I didn't want the annoying flickering that happens with all the answers here, so I've done this: http://android-know-how-to.blogspot.co.il/2013/12/requestfeature-must-be-called-before.html
Its not trivial but it is doable... USE WITH CAUTION!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,yourActivity.class);

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Intent i =  new Intent(YourActivity.this, YourActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps easier is this...

`this.recreate();`

there's some restriction about API less than 11 I think - you'd want to look that up if your app supports API less than 11.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
finish();
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
startActivity(intent);
```